# looking for option to change switch case to something else

Tags: java

I have piece of code that I want to change, I think I can do it better but I have no idea how.
The code should get an option and to do changes (two changes of the constants) according to the string (option) that he gets.
here is the actual code:

```
    public static void setMissingField(String missingField) {
    switch (missingField) {
        case "firstName":
            expectedFirstName = "";
            break;
        case "lastName":
            expectedLastname = "";
            expectedFirstName = "test";
            break;
        case "email":
            expectedWorkEmail = "";
            expectedLastname = "test";
            break;
        case "shortEmail":
            expectedWorkEmail = "12@yes";
            expectedLastname = "test";
            break;
        case "invalidEmail":
            expectedWorkEmail = "asb@@abc.com";
            expectedLastname = "test";
            break;
        case "company":
            expectedCompany = "";
            expectedWorkEmail = "abd@thank.you";
            break;
        case "password":
            expectedPassword = "";
            expectedCompany = "dontAsk";
            break;
        case "shortPassword":
            expectedPassword = "12Aa@";
            expectedCompany = "dontAsk";
            break;
        case "withoutLowerCasePassword":
            expectedPassword = "PASSWORD1@";
            expectedCompany = "dontAsk";
            break;
        case "withoutUpperCasePassword":
            expectedPassword = "password1!";
            expectedCompany = "dontAsk";
            break;
        case "withoutNumberPassword":
            expectedPassword = "Password!";
            expectedCompany = "dontAsk";
            break;
        case "withoutSpecialCharacterPassword":
            expectedPassword = "Password1";
            expectedCompany = "dontAsk";
            break;
        case "confirmationPassword":
            expectedConfirmPassword = "";
            expectedPassword = "Password1@";
            break;
    }
}
```

it suppose to change the constants :

```
public static String expectedFirstName = "test";
public static String expectedLastname = "test";
public static String expectedWorkEmail = "abd@thank.you";
public static String expectedCompany = "dontAsk";
public static String expectedPassword = "Password1@";
public static String expectedConfirmPassword = "Password1@";
```

I thought maybe to use Map but eventhough it will be if statments(on the options itself) and after it PUT on the key values, but that look for me the same, so any good idea?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this "better"; if you have multiple conditions to branch off of, a switch is conventional (which is preferred over nested if statements).  A map is just a structure and you'd still have to have some logic to pull the values out of it if you need.

Comment: Thanks, even if Map, it will be two maps, one to compare the misssingField in map and the other map is to change the values of the expected..so no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch statement is the preferable approach in your described use case.
Especially with more than 3 different possible branches you should convert from multiple if statements to a switch statement. So you are already following this convention.

A Map is only a different data structure. I don't see any benefits of using one in this use case.

Comment: and any other possiblities? not map, something else?